# Recreate gitlabs nginx conf file

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I just deleted my gitlab omnibus nginx conf file. Is it possible to recreate?

with `gitlab-ci reconfigure` does not seems to work. However I see some ruby template which is responsible to create nginx conf

Comment: What config file do you mean? In `../gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` you have an annotation, that `This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
and run sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure.`

Comment: I mean `gitlab-http.conf` this one is not recreated with gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Comment: The gitlab-http.conf file has the same annotation saying that it's managed by gitlab-ctl...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, [`nginx-gitlab-http.conf`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/nginx-gitlab-http.conf.erb) is managed by `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

Note that it is called `nginx-gitlab-http.conf`, not `gitlab-http.conf`.
It is used in [`gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/nginx.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/nginx.rb#L110) in order to generate [`gitlab-http.conf`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/nginx.rb#L43-L45)

Upon a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, you should see:

```
Recipe: gitlab::nginx
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/etc] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/etc/gitlab-http.conf] action create (up to date)
  ...
```

Double-check your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` for any difference which might explain why this file is not recreated.

Make sure to do a `sudo` (as in `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`) to avoid any permission issue.